# simplifying Tuple schemas

Tags: apache-pig

After a long set of commands a schema that started out simple such as

```
A: {state: chararray,m_inc: int,s_err1: bytearray,interval: int}
```

has ended up looking like this:

```
describe L;
L: {null::F::null::null::state: chararray,null::F::null::null::m_inc: int,null::F::null::null::s_err1: bytearray,null::F::null::null::interval: int,m_inc_nrmlzd: double}
```

Is there an easy way to dig these columns out so that its back to a simpler schema?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like that :

```
L = FOREACH L GENERATE null::F::null::null::state AS state:chararray, null::F::null::null::m_inc AS m_inc:int, ...
```